# Regular expression in java to extract URl from HTML

Tags: regex

I am new to **regexes**. I need help.

My HTML source is

```
<a  href="http://www.google.com"></a>
<img src ="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap ="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="http://www.sun.htm" alt="Sun">
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="http://www.mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="http://www.www.venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

I’m trying to extract all href links out like http://www.google.com. 
kindly help.

My Regex is

```
"href=[\\\"\\'](http:\\/\\/|\\.\\/|\\/)?\\w+(\\.\\w+)*(\\/\\w+(\\.\\w+)?)*(\\/|\\?\\w*=\\w*(&\\w*=\\w*)*)?[\\\"\\']"
```

it wil extract like  `href="http://www.google.com"`

But I need only link `http://www.google.com` without  `href=`

Comment: please put the html source in the `code` tags so we can see it!

Answer (score 1):

Please use a XML-parser for this kind of stuff.